# Visualforce dataTable: is there a way to stop it from rendering cellpadding attribute?

Tags: css, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

In Visualforce, I'm using an `<apex:dataTable>` component as follows:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!Qualifications}" var="qual" styleClass="cv_table" >
    <!-- etc...  -->
```

... and then I'm using CSS to style the table, via the class name. Trouble is, VisualForce renders HTML like this:

```
<table class="cv_table" id="j_id0:j_id26" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <!-- etc...  -->
```

The class attribute is there as I wanted, but there's also cellpadding and cellspacing specified, that interfere with my CSS.

Is there a way to stop Visualforce from rendering the cellpadding and cellspacing attributes for an `<apex:dataTable>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like abandoning the `<apex:dataTable>` tag and using the more low-fi `<apex:repeat>` tag might be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned above, have you tried removing the attributes? Specify the id

```
<apex:dataTable id="myTable" value="{!Qualifications}"...
```

then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myTable").removeAttribute("cellpadding");
  document.getElementById("myTable").removeAttribute("cellspacing")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about providing your own values for these (same as in the CSS)? Ugly but would work.

Other than that - attribute removal / reapplying the class with JavaScript?

I don't think that even removal of SalesForce CSS (`<apex:page ... showHeader="false">`) will accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can suppress those attributes in Visualforce.

But if the question you're really asking is how do I not let those attributes affect my overall design, then I think CSS can help.

The CSS equivalent of `cellpadding` is 'padding', and the CSS equivalent of `cellspacing` is 'border-spacing'.  The latter only works on elements of type TD as far as I know.

```
.cv_table TD {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm a devout believer in CSS, but the cellpadding attribute seems to be overriding it, which is why I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Try using !important after the parameters, e.g. "border-spacing: 5px !important;"

That *should* override the other values with some luck. Otherwise, as below, use the low-fi repeat & html combo, that's my usual anyway.